# Why did the Unknown kill so many people?

Tags: dark

In the 3rd season of Dark, the character of [the Unknown](https://dark-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unknown) is introduced. At first, every time he appears, he usually appears as three copies of himself - a boy, a middle-aged man, and an old man -, approaching a single person, and killing them.

Rather than killing certain persons whose death used to be important in one of the timelines, it seemed like he habitually killed everyone he got in touch with - **why? Did he have any particular goal or strategy?** For instance, why did Claudia Tiedemann's secretary at the power plant have to die? Was he just covering up traces?

Comment: I don't remember the scene with the secretary well enough to make it an answer but he didn't kill people in got in touch with, he got in touch with people he had to killed. He was basically weaponized by Eva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**His end goal is to ensure his own existence, and that requires killing people, no matter how many**

The plot revolves around the constant battle between Adam and Eva to achieve their goals. Adam wants to destroy the knot and end the suffering, while Eva wants to preserve it. The Unknown is the son of Adam and Eva, but he only works for his mother. It's more like a co-dependent relationship because, Eva needs The Unknown's aid to execute her plans, while The Unknown would cease to exist if Eva's plans to *preserving the knot* fails. He cannot work for Adam, simply because Adam's plans would eventually erase The Unknown from the existence.

I don't think he enjoys killing or seeing chaos, he kills people because **his sole existence depends on executing Eva's plan, and that involves killing people**. Now, that you have mentioned

> it seemed like he habitually killed everyone he got in touch with

Simply because no one could know his existence or his plans. A rule of thumb of time travel is that the less you reveal to other people, the better. The only people who are aware of The Unknown's existence are Adam, Eva, Claudia and probably a few members from Sic Mundus(I can be wrong here). He could not risk revealing his existence or his plans to the outer world. That could have resulted in drastic consequences.

> why did Claudia Tiedemann's secretary at the power plant have to die

Yes, like you mention in the next line, he's covering up the traces.

Comment: To support the idea that he didn't want his existence/plans known you could also quote the dialogue in the scene where he killed Gustav Tannhaus (near the beginning of S3E3), there it seemed like his specific reason for killing Gustav was that Gustav was planning to reveal the existence of the "travelers" to the world.